# Displaying database records in a grid/ table using vb.net (2010)

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb.net 2010 to code an app that displays data on a form from an access database in a table/grid as shown below. The display must be dynamic not static as in the form below.

[image]

Each database record in the form has the attributes Name e.g "Room1", cost, description, and an OLE Object representing the image. The form above is not connected to any database it just displays static images and text.

I need help on how I can retrieve data from the database and display it as shown above not in a datagridview. Thank you.

Comment: as i read this what i understand is that you don't need help :P where's the question and where is your code? where is the error?

Comment: Questions of the form *"I want to do X, tell me how"* aren't valid here at SO.  This site is for getting help with specific issues.  Not knowing how to do what you want is not a specific issue.  It's a reason to do some research.  Once you have done the research and think you know what to do, do it.  If you run into a specific issue while doing it, that would be the time to ask an actual question, providing all the details about the issue.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I would not have asked if the solution was all over the internet. The solutions that I have found use a datagridview which is what I don't want to use.

Comment: Exactly, post some code and we'll help you fix it, none of us is a freelancer here. And jmcilhinney just gave you the answer, Minathe if you like android it doesn't mean searching for a .net answer should be someone else's work :)